# How to create a copy of state data minus some properties in React?

Tags: reactjs, copy, state

I have state data that I want to convert to JSON such as

```
state = {
    name: “John”
    age: 24
    height: “180cm”
    id: 2
}
```

How would I go about creating a copy of this state minus the id property?

So

```
copy = {
    name: “John”
    age: 24
    height: “180cm”
}
```

I’ve tried using the filter function but it doesn’t seem to work on this.state?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var state = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 24,
  height: '180 cm',
  id: 2
};

// you need to filter the keys of the object
var keysToKeep = Object.keys(state).filter(key => key != 'id');

var copy = keysToKeep.reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = state[key];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(copy);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const { id, ...copy } = state;
```

This [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) results in a local declaration of `id` and an object called `copy` that contains all the remaining keys (and values) of `state` that are *not* `id`.

See the following snippet for context.

```js
const state = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 24,
  height: '180 cm',
  id: 2
};

const { id, ...copy } = state;

console.log(copy);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this,

```js
let state = {
  name: "John",
  age: 24,
  height: "180cm",
  id: 2
}
let copy = {}

Object.keys(state).forEach(k => {
  if(k !== 'id') {
    copy[k] = state[k]
  }
})

console.log(copy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
const state = {
    name: "John",
    age: 24,
    height: "180cm",
    id: 2
}
const newState = {...state}
delete newState.id
```

This will create a `newState` object instead of manipulating the original `state` object (which would cause issues). And then it will update the `newState` object to remove the `id`.

Then you can move forward working with the `newState` object.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

the approach I would take is called destructuring and it would look something like this:

```
{name,age,height}= this.state;
```

and then copy all the elements to a new variable

```
const copystate= {name,age,height}
```

Comment: What if state contains multiple elements (e.g. 100+). Destructuring is not a good idea.

Comment: I agree  if it had more than 10 elements destructuring would not be viable but with 4 objects I would say is an easy approach.

Comment: @ravibagul91 in that case you can use rest: `const {removed,...newState} = state;` now newState is state minus removed. If removed is a string you can do `const {[keyToRemove]:gone,...newState}=state`

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = {
    name: "John",
    age: 24,
    height: "180cm",
    id: 2
}

const { id, ...rest} = obj;
```

`rest` is now all properties but `id`

Answer (score 0):

If you have lodash at the project

```
import omit from 'lodash/omit';

const newState = omit(oldState, ['id']);
```

If you haven’t lodash at the project

```
const { id, ...newState } = oldState;
```